# Access shared folder in VirtualBox from command prompt Host Ubuntu Guest Win7

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, virtualbox

I have Win7 installed in VirtualBox as guest and I've shared my "MyFolder" for this.
So, I can see it in guest's Windows Explorer as "MyFolder(\\vboxsrv) (E:)"
How can I access this folder from command prompt?
**E:** and **pushd \\vboxrsv** don't work

Comment: Did you try `pushd \\vboxsvr\MyFolder `. If your drive is mapped properly then **E:** should be able to do it.

Comment: I don't know why but after I did what I posted in my answer - everything works - E: and cd \d E:. Before It hadn't worked.

Comment: Nice. Might have been a mapping issue.

Comment: If you have a solution to the issue post it and mark it as an answer

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml I've posted the answer already, but I don't know If it's an universal solution, because I can't describe what was the real problem. It's like JustForMe solution on JustForMyProblem )

Comment: If it solves YOUR problem/question it must be marked as an answer

Comment: @GriMel, I also have this intermittent problem. Sometimes, when I do `pushd \\servername\sharename` it works.. sometimes it doesn't. In your case is the problem also intermittent or repeatable?

Comment: @alpha_989 Intermittent. That's confusing, agree)

Comment: Are you running the VM in `Bridge Networking` mode, or `NATNetwork`? Wondering if there is there is common configuration.. they it would be easier to figure out the root cause...

Comment: @GriMel, I think its solved for me.. Here's the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50780399/4752883. Let us know if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually ran **cmd** from within File Explorer and now I can access **E:**

1. Open File Explorer
2. Go to **E:**
3. Click **Alt+D**
4. Enter **cmd**
5. PROFIT!

It's not an universal solution, but in my case it solved the issue.

Comment: Just wondering: if you started cmd normally, couldn't you have changed the directory with `cd /d e:\`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem **when using an elevated command prompt**. In this case I needed to map the same drive letter again. From within the elevated command prompt do

`net use`

This will show the correctly mapped drive letter, but the letter is inaccessible from within the elevated command promt. Then map the same drive letter again:

`net use f: \\vboxsrv\Shared`

Now F: is accessible.

The reason is that elevated command prompts usually create a new logon session which do not share the symbolic links with the existing login sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You must first install **VirtualBox extension pack** then:

1- Create a shared folder in virtual box and check the **auto-mount** and **Make permanent** checkboxes.
2- In your Windows, open the **Command Prompt**
3- Type **E:** and press **Enter**.(**E** is your shared folder drive in File explorer)

Finish :).

Comment: after creating share folder, you must reboot your machine.

Comment: Not a solution to the ops problem. He can see the drive letter E: in the Explorer already.

Answer (score 0):

My best experience has been to make a scheduled task that runs on system start using the following command:

`schtasks /create /tn "user_mount" /tr "net use \\user\20034 /user:user_user password /persistent:yes" /sc onstart /RU SYSTEM /rl highest`

Just because you have the `/persistent` tag on doesn't mean it will survive restarts.

I was getting very intermittent connections to my server, this pretty much solved it 100%.